# Having an issue with a repeating bg image

Tags: css, image

I am trying to have a header image with a border at the top of my page above my content area but for some reason my bg image is repeating.  Do you know what is causing the image to repeat?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container_12">
<div class="subheader">
<img src="images/subheader_1.png" alt="Subheader" width="940px" height="240px" />
</div>
</div>
```

here is my CSS:

```
.subheader{background:url(../images/subheader_1.png);background-repeat:no-repeat; min-height:300px; width:940px}

.subheader img {border:1px solid #ccc;padding:5px;background:#efefef}
```

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Here is a screen shot of what is happening.http://i48.photobucket.com/albums/f228/bad03xtreme/Screenshot2012-06-06at12306PM.png

Comment: That doesn't look like it's repeating, it looks like the border, padding, margin, or some combo is showing the image pushed slightly down and to the right, revealing the same background image. Why are you even applying a background image behind the image you have?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You've only specified the `background` attribute in your css. This is a global attribute expecting all settings defined there. To couple the `background-repeat` with an image you have to use `background-image`:</strike>

**Edit:**
Based on your edit and posted screen shot, it looks like you don't have a repeating image so much as you've included the image in both the background AND an image tag. You should pick one or the other, but to get it to line up right, you need to remove the padding and margin:

```
.subheader img {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:5px;    <--- TAKE THIS OUT
    margin: 0px;    <--- ADD THIS
    background:#efefef
}
```

Comment: I don't think that should matter as the background-repeat rule should override the background rule. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qzRkh/

Comment: @j08691: It shouldn't matter, but I've seen it before. Given your fiddle, though, I'll remove. It's clearly working there.

Comment: @j08691: I've update the answer based on his comment/screen shot.

Comment: Alright, that just removed my border.  What I am trying to do is have a placeholder div for each page that I can have various bg images in according to the page content.  The .subheder img style was for the border that goes around the image itself.  I hope I am not going about this completely wrong please forgive my ignorance.